# Using PL/PerlU with a non system perl lib

Tags: postgresql

```
psql -1f check_email.pl.sql ccushing postgres
SET
psql:check_email.pl.sql:7: ERROR:  Can't locate Email/Valid.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl .) at line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at line 3.
CONTEXT:  compilation of PL/Perl function "check_email"
```

My current `@INC` is

```
@INC:
  /home/ccushing/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.2/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/x86_64-linux
  /home/ccushing/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.2/lib/site_perl/5.14.2
  /home/ccushing/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.2/lib/5.14.2/x86_64-linux
  /home/ccushing/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.2/lib/5.14.2
```

obviously my problem is that `Email::Valid` is not in my `@INC`, can I globally change Postgres @INC Paths? also related is postgres only capable of using the Perl it's built against? or can I make it use my `perlbrew`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just push it into @INC before you use it? At the first line in your func? I'm pretty sure that should work.

PostgreSQL will only use the perl it's built against. You'd have to rebuild it (or at least plperl) against your custom perl.

Comment: well part of the problem was that `postgres` didn't have read access to that directory. I ended up giving a  `local::lib` to postgres

Comment: @xenoterracide How did you give postgres a "local::lib"? -- If the related env vars are in my .bashrc, will that be adequate enough for the postgres install to see them?